# R: Change a value of an entry based on consecutive entry (with an unequal spacing between the two) in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataset, rows

I need to edit some markers for ER purposes in my brain imaging data which basically means that I need to change a value of an entry if the first consecutive nonzero entry is of a certain value. I don't know whether or not I need to write a custom function for it (and in case I'd needed to do that, some nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated).

Better to illustrate my problem on an example(let's assume that col markers is a snippet of 16000-row dataset containing information about marker values):

```
markers = matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3), ncol = 1)
```

I need to change a value 1 to (f.e.) value 9 if the next nonzero entry is 2 (but not if it is 3). There is no equal spacing between these (meaning, there might be 3-8 zero entries between these two entries of interest.

I'd be glad for any help because I really don't want to have to change those values manually :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the most straightforward way, but here is an approach using base R::
I will write it step by step so you can see what is happening in each step.

First do `rle`

```
b <- rle(markers[,1])$values
```

check which elements are 1

```
z <- which(b==1)
```

now check if 0 is one element ahead if yes take the index of two elements ahead

```
k <- ifelse(b[z + 1] == 0, z + 2, z + 1)
```

now check if those elements are equal to 2, remove any that are not

```
v <- ifelse(b[k] == 2, z, NA)
v <- na.omit(v)
```

change the values of indexes that are left to 9

```
b[v] = 9
```

get the vector back

```
rep(b, times = rle(markers[,1])$lengths)
#output
[1] 9 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3

markers[,1]
#output
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3
```

Here is a little benchmark:

```
evers <- function(markers){require(dplyr);
  df <- sapply(1:nrow(markers), function(i) lead(markers, i - 1))
  idx <- which(df[, 1] == 1);
  idx
  idx <- idx[sapply(idx, function(i) any(df[i, 2:nrow(df)] == 2, na.rm = TRUE))]}

mss <- function(markers) {
  b <- rle(markers[,1])$values
  z <- which(b==1)
  k <- ifelse(b[z + 1] == 0, z + 2, z + 1)
  v <- ifelse(b[k] == 2, z, NA)
  v <- na.omit(v)
  b[v] = 9 

  rep(b, times = rle(markers[,1])$lengths)
  b
}

microbenchmark(
mss(markers),
evers(markers)
)
#Unit: microseconds
           expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq       max neval
   mss(markers)  42.667  45.555 118.2324  50.046  52.1315  6681.986   100
 evans(markers) 128.322 133.775 271.2453 136.021 140.6725 12645.376   100
```

with a bigger data set:

```
markers = matrix(rep(c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3), times = 1000), ncol = 1)
#output
Unit: microseconds
           expr       min           lq        mean       median          uq         max neval
   mss(markers)     823.5     904.5025    1144.658     957.5945    1045.174     5455.24   100
 evans(markers) 2940719.3 3185982.7470 3453372.766 3242533.4130 3299607.308 11652090.81   100
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough instruction! It seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
markers <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3), ncol = 1)
```

Create a `dataframe` of all possible lagged versions of `markers`.

```
# Create dataframe of lagged vectors
require(dplyr);
df <- sapply(1:nrow(markers), function(i) lead(markers, i - 1));
```

Get row indices where entries in the unlagged vector are equal to 1.

```
# Select rows where entry = 1
idx <- which(df[, 1] == 1);
idx;
#[1]  1 11
```

Keep only those indices where for row `idx` there exists an entry equals 2 in `any` of the lagged versions of `markers`.

```
# Keep only those rows where entry = 1 followed by a lagged 2
idx <- idx[sapply(idx, function(i) any(df[i, 2:nrow(df)] == 2, na.rm = TRUE))];
```

Finally set the values for those rows equal to 9.

```
# Set those entries equal to 9
markers[idx, 1] <- 9;

markers;
#      [,1]
# [1,]    9
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    2
# [7,]    0
# [8,]    0
# [9,]    0
#[10,]    0
#[11,]    1
#[12,]    0
#[13,]    0
#[14,]    0
#[15,]    3
```

---

### Update

With your second `markers` example:

```
markers <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3), ncol = 1);
df <- sapply(1:nrow(markers), function(i) lead(markers, i - 1));
idx <- which(df[, 1] == 1);
idx <- idx[sapply(idx, function(i) any(df[i, 2:nrow(df)] == 2, na.rm = TRUE))];
markers[idx, 1] <- 9;
markers;
#      [,1]
# [1,]    9
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    2
# [7,]    0
# [8,]    0
# [9,]    0
#[10,]    0
#[11,]    9
#[12,]    0
#[13,]    0
#[14,]    0
#[15,]    2
#[16,]    0
#[17,]    0
#[18,]    0
#[19,]    0
#[20,]    1
#[21,]    0
#[22,]    0
#[23,]    0
#[24,]    0
#[25,]    3
```

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr-based code Maurits, but I encountered an error(Error in df[i, 2:nrow(df)] : subscript out of bounds) when I added a few additional values to the matrix (markers <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,3), ncol = 1)). I don't know why is that, cause I don't know the rationale behind the lagged versions (well, I think I know why, but not how), but I'll investigate it in in the morning.

Comment: @ayasugihada Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I had two errors in my code from testing different approaches. I've fixed it and (as far as I can tell) it should work now on your updated example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it today on my real data and compare it with the second approach by missuse.